# return null instead of nothing if there are no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, resultset, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic sql statement that may or may not return any results. For simplicity sake:

```
--other SQL statements defining @a
DECLARE @sql varchar(128)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a = ' + @a
EXEC(@sql)
```

I want the results if this statement returns any but if `EXEC(@sql)` does not return any results how can I go about making it return a single `null` instead?

I am working with MS SQLServer 2000.

**EXPLANATION FOR X-ZERO**

This is for use in a webapp ajax response. I am not able to alter the backend java framework which requires a resultset of some kind to be returned by the query to the webservice.

**SOLUTION**

In case anyone else has this question and because it wasn't totally clear in the answers, this worked:

```
--other SQL statements defining @a
DECLARE @sql varchar(128)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a = ' + @a
EXEC(@sql)
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SELECT null
```

Comment: So, instead of a result table, you want a single string?  I suppose you could do something with `COALESCE()`, but this strikes me as troublesome all around.  _Why_ are you doing this?

Comment: @X-Zero Sorry not a string I meant an actual `null` I will make that clearer. I'll add explanation above.

Comment: If you're doing this as part of the backend webservice, can you just inspect the query meta information for rows returned, and return `null` from whatever function is running the query (I think @Barry is recommending this, but I'm not sure).

Comment: @X-Zero Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. Running two queries where one would do is not an efficient use of resources.

Comment: @X-Zero As mentioned, I can not alter the java webservice which uses `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` method that requires a resultset to be returned. That's why I needed a null in SQL code. The solution works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result set record count of the statement with the same WHERE clause, and it it is zero, then you can just return one record with null value.

Example:

```
declare @sql varchar(128)
declare @a varchar(10);
set @a = '''Some @a value''';

declare @rowcount int;
exec sp_executesql N'select @rowcount=count(*) FROM c WHERE a = ''Some @a value''', 
                    N'@rowcount int output', @rowcount output;

if @rowcount <> 0
begin
  select @sql = 'SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a = ' + @a
end
else
begin
  select @sql = 'select null';
end

exec(@sql)                    ;
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Added a full example (not tested, but probably working) :D, to help others that view this question in the future.

Comment: A `WHERE NOT EXISTS` version may be more efficient than counting rows (especially if the count is large), as well as conveying the purpose better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want the statement to return a single row consisting of `null` when no rows are returned from the actual query. Or, put another way, you want it to return a value (null) when it's supposed to return no values.

I think what you should do instead is leave the query as-is and get a count of the number of rows returned by the statement. I believe you can do this with the `@@rowcount` variable after doing the query.

(Disclaimer: What I know about SQL Server I learned from Google and S.O.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option avoiding `@@ROWCOUNT` would be to save the results in a table variable, then return the results if any exist or `NULL` if they don't. E.g:

```
DECLARE @results TABLE(a int, b int)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(128)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a = ' + @a

insert into @results
exec (@sql)

IF EXISTS(select top 1 * from @results)
SELECT * from @results
ELSE SELECT null
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the SQL Docs on MAX(Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks). "MAX returns NULL when there is no row to select.". I should give credit to [this answer on SqlServerCentral](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-return-null-or-value-when-nothing-is-returned-from-query#post-1393340).

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(128)
SET @sql = 'SELECT MAX(a), MAX(b) FROM c WHERE a = ' + @a
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```